# Java project which runs fine in Inteliji, can't compile in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, java-17

Quick disclaimer: It's my 1st day at work and the following project has been written by my superior. All of this is very new to me so thank you for being patient.

Now to the point. So I received a java project that uses jdk 17. So today I tried to run it in VSCode using the Java Language Support and Java Debugger extensions. It showed some critical errors.
[vscode showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q15Ve.png)

So when I right clicked it and chose 'Run Java' on my 'RifseepApplication.java', it showed lots of compiling errors and the application crashed.
[the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjEoq.png)

But when I open the exact project in Inteliji, it detects no errors in the code and I can run it perfectly.

So jdk version in Inteliji was set to 17 for the project, so I tried to change jdk version in VScode too. I added to 'settings.json':

```
{   "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.4.101-hotspot",
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
        "name": "JavaSE-17",
        "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.4.101-hotspot"
        }
    ]
}
```

And when I check in the terminal, [the jdk and java version are all good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7xQe.png)
But the editor is still showing errors in the code and I still can't compile and run my application.
If someone has some insights to this, please share.
Thank you.

Comment: "showing errors" ... likely you have classes on your intellij path that aren't on your classpath

Comment: can you explain further? how does the paths work?

Comment: then use Intelliji, VSC  is an editor not an IDE

Comment: What kind of quick fix does the little yellow light bulb next to the red squiggly line provide? Also the level after your package is not the same as your actual directory level. Try modifying it and see if that resolves the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by looking at what `quick fix` the little yellow light bulb next to the red squiggly line offers.

[image]

Then according to your screenshot,the level after your package is not the same as your actual directory level. Please modify to the correct directory structure.

[image]

Comment: That was indeed the problem! I did notice when I first saw the error but since my project leader said it works fine on her end when built with Inteliji, I thought maybe it's a problem with vscode. Turns out as the package is not yet used, Inteliji still allows the program to run, but VSCode doesn't. I guess this is my first lesson as an employee: Not everything written by my superior is correct!

Answer (score 0):

That was very dumb of me. The problem was indeed the wrong package declration for "...presentation.controllers.dto". It wasn't in the right place. Seems like somehow Inteliji has data of the previous build of this project so it can still runs fine. There wasn't any version problem with VScode or anything.